# Expresión regular

Tags: javascript, nodejs, regex

Buenos días quería solicitar ayuda con una expresión regular en javascript

Tengo el siguiente texto

> ```
> F[gg(1; F[dd(texto)])] + F[gg(1;2)]
> ```

lo cual al aplicarle la siguiente expresión regular

```
/F\[([^F\[\]]+)\]/g;
```

obtengo un array con lo siguiente

```
[ 'F[dd(texto)]', 'F[gg(1;2)]' ]
```

Lo cual es perfecto para lo que ando buscando , el problema lo tengo cuando hay una letra F mayuscula en el texto ejemplo :

> ```
> F[gg(1; F[dd(textoFecha)])] + F[gg(1;2)]
> ```

Obtengo :

```
[ 'F[gg(1;2)]' ]
```

Y Me gustaría obtener

```
[ 'F[dd(textoFecha)]', 'F[gg(1;2)]' ]
```

EDIT*

```
F[funAvgOver(F[SI(HHOROM>0;HHOROM;F[SI(1=1; (dbo.FN_CtrlMineria_ObtenerConstante(29, 'k1' )) ;0)])]; EQ, FECHA_FN ; FECHA_FN)]
```

Y obtuve los siguientes resultados para las diferentes expresiones

```
/F\[([^F\[\]]+)\]/g :

null



/F\[([^\[\]]+)\]/g : 

[ 'F[SI(1=1; (dbo.FN_CtrlMineria_ObtenerConstante(29, \'k1\' )) ;0)]' ]


/F\[([^[]+)]/g :

[ 'F[SI(1=1; (dbo.FN_CtrlMineria_ObtenerConstante(29, \'k1\' )) ;0)])]; EQ, FECHA_FN ; FECHA_FN)]' ]
```

Por lo que la que estaría funcionando por el momento seria

```
/F\[([^\[\]]+)\]/g
```

Comment: Si le quitas la `F` dejandolo `/F\[([^\[\]]+)\]/g` funciona. ¿tienes algun otro test que falle asi? Lo más que puedo simplificarla para que funcione con tus ejemplos es `/F\[([^[]+)]/g` (los `\ ` que quite no son necesarios delante de `[` por el contexto de uso de los mismos)

Comment: Hola, sigues necesitando ayuda para esta pregunta. Te sirvió el comentario de lois6b?

Answer (score 1):

Veamos, según lo que yo interpreto de tus condiciones, siempre el `F[`..`]` interno:

- que empiece por `F[`
- que no tenga un `F[` en el medio
- que tampoco tenga un `]` en el medio porque
- no tiene anidados y termina con `]`

**Regex**

```regex
/F\[((?:[^F\]]+|F(?!\[))+)\]/
```

La clave está en `(?:[^F\]]+|F(?!\[))+` que son 2 opciones:

1. `[^F\]]+` caracteres que no sean ninguno de esos 2
2. `F(?!\[)` una `F` [que no esté seguida](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) de un `[`, y así hacemos coincidir el caso que te estaba trayendo problemas con un F dentro del texto.

**Ejemplo**:

```js
let pruebas = [
               'F[gg(1; F[dd(texto)])] + F[gg(1;2)]',
               'F[gg(1; F[dd(textoFecha)])] + F[gg(1;2)]',
               "F[funAvgOver(F[SI(HHOROM>0;HHOROM;F[SI(1=1; (dbo.FN_CtrlMineria_ObtenerConstante(29, 'k1' )) ;0)])]; EQ, FECHA_FN ; FECHA_FN)]"
              ],
    regex = /F\[((?:[^F\[\]]+|F(?!\[))+)\]/g,
    match;

for (let texto of pruebas) {
    console.log('PROBANDO:', texto);
    while (match = regex.exec(texto)){
        console.log("-Coincide con:\t", match[0], "\t|Captura:\t", match[1]);
    }
}
```